Damping functions
I am reaching out to discuss the concept of damped functions. Specifically, I am interested in understanding which functions can be categorized as damped. Can all trigonometric functions be damped? Additionally, is it possible for any function to be damped?
To clarify for those unfamiliar with the term "damped" in this context, I am referring to a function whose graph is bounded by the positive and negative versions of another graph. For example, the function
$y=x\sin(x)$ is bounded by
$y= \pm x$.
If my explanation is unclear, please do not hesitate to ask for further clarification.
Best regards.
Note for anyone who asked the explanation from my textbook here It is please not e that since I ma getting ready for an exam I can't transcript all of it an hope that the screenshot will be enough momentarily until I can change it:



More importantly:  I'd have thought that "damping" required that the bounding functions go to $0$ at $\infty$.  Otherwise any bounded function is "damped".

no I mena like try to graph y=±x and y=xsinx and you will see what I mean y=± contains y=xsinx

But that definition doesn't make a lot of sense.  For instance $e^x$ is bounded by $\pm(e^x+1)$.  Is $e^x$ damped?  And, as a general point, it's not a great idea to use standard terminology in unexpected ways.

In which book, did you find the term damped functions to define such functions that is bounded by other functions?

I ill share the immage of my book defining this right away thanks for the comment

Sure, a definition of damped functions with some more examples would be a clearer and finer approach.

here we go hope this helps.

please let me know for any further concerns.

so there is also a video that I am currently unable to attach that specifies how the functions appears to be contained in the other functions (to which is being multiplied) positive and negative versions.

I am coming up with a better answer if I can

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Note that $\tan (x)$ is not damped so it provides a counterexample for both trig functions and all functions.

ok thanks but more generally of the 6 trig functions with one are damped?\

As the book says, you can surely create more functions that are two product of two independent functions and so have a damping factor. Consider the path the book have taken:
Let say $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=x^2$. Then surely, $h(x)=f(x)g(x)=x^2\sin x$ is such a function where the function $\sin x$ stays between the function $\pm x^2$. By saying, I mean that, there are a number of points when on function acts as a tangent to the other. [They intersect only once, but do not get through one another]
Regarding the case about other such functions, $|\tan x|$ does not have all of its values within range $[0,1]$, so there cannot be such functions for $\tan x$. Similar rules set up for $\cot x$. You can create such bounded functions with $\sec x$ and $\csc x$ too, since they follow the rule that $0\leq f|(x)|\leq1$.
I hope this answer clears your way of understanding how you can create any bounded functions with a damping factor. Choose a function with $0\leq|f(x)|\leq1$ and have $g(x)$.
Can every function be made bounded? Well actually no. First of all, by definition it seems the function must be periodic. This are all trigonometric functions, like $\sin x$ or $\cos x$. Moreover, the range of the function needs to be within $[-1,1]$. Therefore, trigonometric functions like $\tan x$ and $\cot x$ cannot be made bounded functions.
And yes, if you consider these trigonometric functions as main functions, that functions that are bounded within other functions, then obviously there are many functions like that. In fact $\sin (ax)$, $\cos (ax)$, $\csc (ax)$ and $\sec (ax)$, with any real value $a$ can be considered as main functions.

Regarding why $x$ is called a damping factor is that, if the function $f(x)=x\sin x$ would not have been multiplied with $x$, the function $g(x)=\sin x$ would have a greater amplitude. This term work appropriately with oscillatory functions like these trigonometric ones.

So, there are many functions that satisfy
∣
f
(
x
)
∣
≥
1
∣f(x)∣≥1. Are there infinitely many functions that can serve as the "main" function (sinx in xsinx cn be considered the main one) to be multiplied by others? Additionally, I'm still unsure how this applies to all six trigonometric functions (sin, cos, tan, cot, sec, csc).

if you are happy to answer to my questions I will gladly accept your answer

not all trigonometric functions, just the one that has range within $[-1,1]$

but both sine and cosine work right?

momentarily this was the most helpful answer for finding the solution

Yes, it does work.
